# Extracting group dependent results from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe made from different groups, and for each group real and predicted values. I want to extract values of tests on these values :

```
library(dplyr)
 d = data.frame(group = c(rep(5,x="a"),rep(5,x="b")), real = c(rep(2, x=1:5)), pred = c(2,1,3,4,5,1,2,4,3,5))

group real pred
1      a    1    2
2      a    2    1
3      a    3    3
4      a    4    4
5      a    5    5
6      b    1    1
7      b    2    2
8      b    3    4
9      b    4    3
10     b    5    5

 d <- d %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate( sg = ifelse(real == 1 & real == pred, 1, 0))
 d <- d %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate( sp = ifelse(real <= 3 & pred <= 3, 1, 0))
 d %>% distinct(sg, sp)

sg    sp  group
1     0     1      a
2     0     0      a
3     1     1      b
4     0     1      b
5     0     0      b
```

But I want something like this (only 1 result per group)

```
 sg    sp  group
1     0     1      a
3     1     1      b
```

I am pretty sure dplyr, data.table or tidyr can do something but I cannot find how.

Answer (score 0):

If it is always the first row of each group that you want to extract, you could use the `do` function:

`d %>% do(.[1,])`

Another option is to use the filter function like this:

`d %>% filter(seq_along(sp) == 1)`

Comment: Thanks Erich, but what I want is more a combination of all rows within the group. The only solution I found so far was to do mutate(sg = sg || sg )

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "combination of all rows within the group".